# Laravel exists() function keeps returning false when it does exist

Tags: php, laravel

i'm not sure what im doing wrong but every time i click the like button it turns up false

Im using laravel 5.5

it clearly works it when i pass in the post id,  whenever i click it.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/144/islikedbyme
```

my console log shows no errors, the like button works but the isLikedByMe function keeps rendering

> false

in the network log and i don't know why. It works look at the datebase

[image]

**PostController.php**

```
public function isLikedByMe($id)
{
  $post = Post::find($id);

    if (Like::whereUserId(auth()->user()->id)->wherePostId($post)->exists()){
        return 'true';
    }
    return 'false';
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('post/{id}/islikedbyme', 'PostController@isLikedByMe');
Route::post('post/like/{post}', 'PostController@like');
```

**Main.js**

```
$scope.like = function(post) {
    $http.post('/post/like/'+ post.id).then(function(result) {
        $scope.getLike(post);
    });
};



$scope.getLike = function(post){

    $http.get('/post/'+ post.id +'/islikedbyme').then(function(result) {
        if (result == 'true') {
            $scope.like_btn_text = "Like";
        } else {
            $scope.like_btn_text = "Unlike";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think the issue in your query

Comment: can you elaborate im not understanding

Comment: check my below ans may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's removed, if you want even the removed ones do it like this :

```
public function isLikedByMe($id)
{
  $post = Post::find($id);

    if (Like::withTrashed()
             ->whereUserId(auth()->user()->id)
             ->wherePostId($post->id)->exists()){
        return 'true';
    }
    return 'false';
}
```

Or even better if you don't want the post insatance you can do it like this :

```
public function isLikedByMe($id)
{

    if (Like::withTrashed()
             ->whereUserId(auth()->user()->id)
             ->wherePostId($id)->exists()){
        return 'true';
    }
    return 'false';
}
```

Comment: no, its like i click the heart button but it keeps renders false false. let me try this out

Comment: yeah it still renders false

Comment: Check the updated answer you forgot `->id` for the post :)

Comment: one more question

Comment: my main.js script doesn't render a unlike when it is clicked. it stays on like, why could this be ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159967/discussion-between-maraboc-and-barnowl).

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like below :**

```
public function isLikedByMe($id) {
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $is_like = Like::where(['user_id' => auth()->user()->id, 'post_id' => $post->post_id])->exists();
    if ($is_like) {
        return 'true';
    }
    return 'false';
}
```

Comment: yeah it returned false again.